# making getelementbyid plural

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, getelementbyid

In the context of the code below (or anywhere), is it possible for a getelementbyid function to work plurally? Or do I need a different function, or possibly Jquery?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() 
    {
    var test = document.getElementById('test');
    if (test) 
        {
        test.className = 'unactive';
        test.firstChild.onclick = function() 
            {
            if(this.parentNode.className == 'unactive') {
            this.parentNode.className = 'active';
            } 
            else 
                {
                this.parentNode.className = 'unactive';
                }
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Your "id" values are supposed to be unique anyway, so that wouldn't make sense. You can use "class" values to categorize elements so that you can find them in groups.

Comment: What do you mean by *plurally*? You should have only one element for each id. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i think you are asking for `class`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Or do you just want to iterate over a set of IDs? Like `var ids = ["test1", "test2", "test3"]; for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) { test = document.getElementById(ids[i]); /* do stuff here */ }`

Comment: @GoranJovic I'm trying to eliminate the need for getElementById here. The problem is, I don't know what to replace it with, because class doesn't seem to be working. Aside from that, I'm a bit new at this, so I'm kinda fuzzy on how to handle it.

Comment: You should also try to avoid placing javascript in your html try creating a seperate file.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to act on multiple elements using a list of IDs.  (If I am wrong, and you actually want to select multiple elements with the same ID, you have done a Bad Thing, since IDs should be unique. In that case, you should use classes instead.)

**In jQuery,** you can accomplish this with a comma-separated list of id selectors (like `$("#foo, #bar, #baz")`) and implement your function like:

```
$("#foo, #bar, #baz").addClass("unactive")
.children(":first-child").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $parent = $this.parent();
    $parent.toggleClass("active unactive");
});
```

**Without jQuery,** this small function takes a list of IDs and results an array of nodes:

```
document.getElementsByIdList() {
    var results = [];
    for(var i=0; i<arguments.length; ++i) {
        results.push(document.getElementById(arguments[i]));
    }
    return results;
}
```

Use it with you current code with:

```
var myNodeArray = document.getElementsByIdList("foo", "bar", "baz");
for(var i=0; i<myNodeArray.length; ++i) {
    var test = myNodeArray[i];
    if(test) {
        // your code goes in here...
    }
}
```

Comment: how exactly would that function work with mine? It looks great, but I'm kinda new to this. Could you break it down? @apsillers

Comment: @Shimmy I added a bit more context for how you can use my answer with your current code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this;

```
document.getAllById = function(id){
    if(document.all)
        return document.all[id];
    var elements = [],
    all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++)
        if(all[i].getAttribute('id')===id)
            elements.push(all);
    return elements;
}
```

Anyway, as @Pointy said, the `id` attribute is supposed to be unique, while `class` is used to define one or more elements that has some common properties